# Reassign Case Role Not Working in 4.7

Tags: civicase

I'm on Drupal with CiviCRM 4.7.21. I have a case with John Doe as the "Manager." When I try to reassign the individual, I can select a new individual and the form will submit. However, nothing changes after the page reloads. "Manager" is still John Doe.

Can anyone verify this? I don't see any of the CiviCRM demos have CiviCase activated for me to replicate this.

**Steps**

1. Create a custom relationship "Manager is"
2. Create a custom case "Supervision"
3. Add "Manager" case role to Supervision case under case type
4. Open a case
5. Reassign the case role from "Person A" to "Person B"
6. Page is reloaded with no change. Person A remains the case manager.

Comment: Seems to work ok on the demo at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Can you check the logs for errors? (under sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog)

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue on the dmaster demo site. I created a new custom relationship, updated the new case type to include the new case role, and then added the case to an individual. When reassigning the case, nothing happens.

Comment: When I do as you're describing on the demo I don't see the reassign problem (it reassigns ok), but I notice it still has the stock role as the case manager not the new relationship/role I added. Hmm.

Comment: Did you create a new case type with the custom relationship role? I tried it multiple times and it the individual still doesn't update.

Comment: Yes. I think you're going to have to provide an exact list of steps (edit the original post).

Comment: Will do! Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see your config is still on the demo. A key piece of information missing is that the new relationship type is defined for a different type of contact (Student) than the client. If I change the relationship type to be between Individuals it works fine.

The role is a relationship with the CLIENT. If the client is an Individual, the relationship type needs to be one that is also with an Individual.

You could argue it would be nice to have an error popup, but this just seems like a configuration issue - it needs to be the same type as the client.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion was perfect. I needed to set the relationship as Individual to Individual.